# How to tell if mod_deflate is actually working?

Tags: apache-2.2, gzip, mod-deflate

I have put the following in my http.conf file:

```
# mod_deflate configuration
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

# Restrict compression to these MIME types
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css

# Level of compression (Highest 9 - Lowest 1)
DeflateCompressionLevel 9

# Netscape 4.x has some problems.
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

# Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

# MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
# Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

My content doesn't return with a Content-Encoding of type gzip, but I find myself getting a lot more 304s and the Etag is appended with a +gzip suffix. Is mod_deflate actually doing its job? (Sorry about the n00b-ishness)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What do the headers tell you, if it is not returning "content-encoding: gzip" it's probably not working.. you can test as follows:

```
curl -I -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate' http://yoursite.com/somefile
```

Comment: like I said, it doesn't return a Content-Encoding header at all

Comment: `-I` tells curl to only fetch headers by using an HTTP HEAD request. In my case (an apache2 server), the HEAD request returns 302 and no Content-Encoding header. To test what's happening for the actual GET request, use `-v -o /dev/null` instead of `-I`.

Answer (score 2):

The apache docs for [AddOutputFilterByType](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#addoutputfilterbytype) indicate this directive is deprecated in Apache httpd 2.1 and later and it doesn't always work well if Apache can not determine the mime type.

I would suggest enabling compressing by using something like the following as a starting point and then add all the browser tweaks and compression levels back in.  Obviously, you may want to double check httpd.conf to make sure it's actually loading mod_deflate.so as well:

```
<Location />
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Don't compress images
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$ no-gzip dont-vary
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</Location>
```

Use cURL as mentioned by Michael Steinfeld to verify.

Comment: apache 2.4 upgrade doc seems to indicate that it will automagically determine whether or not to gzip a given resource: "mod_deflate will now skip compression if it knows that the size overhead added by the compression is larger than the data to be compressed" -- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html

Comment: In `httpd-2.4` this `AddOutputFilterByType` directive is corrected, un-deprecated and moved to `filter_module`.

Comment: `Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary` i think you should not do that. googve `vary` header, quite long disccusions about that.

Answer (score 2):

Can't add acomment as I don't have enough reputation therefore I am writing this as an answer.

The original answer by Michael Steinfeld was outputting the following error (on Windows Command Prompt)

`curl: (6) Could not resolve host: gzip,deflate'`

I solved it by removing the space after the colon:

`curl -I -H 'Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate' http://yoursite.com/somefile`

Answer (score 1):

With [`LogLevel`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#loglevel) set to `debug`, mod_deflate will log its debug messages to [`ErrorLog`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errorlog). Every resource that is being compressed gets logged out there. You can see if mod_deflate is working in real-time with

```
tail -f /path/to/error-log | grep deflate
```

e.g.

> [Wed Apr 22 05:37:49.742615 2015] [deflate:debug] [pid 22627] mod_deflate.c(849): [client 127.0.0.1:55667] AH01384: Zlib: Compressed 10700 to 2637 : URL /web/js/common.js, referer: http://localhost/index.php